# ¿Función nativa para encontrar ocurrencias dentro de un string?

Tags: php

¿Existe la función que obtenga las posiciones en que aparece un string dentro de otro?
Tengo la siguiente función para hacer esto:

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";


function getPositions( $str, $needle ) {

    $arr = array();
    while ( $str && (( $pos = mb_strrpos( $str, $needle )) > 0 || $pos === 0 )) {
        //echo $str . "<br>"; //traza

        $str = mb_substr( $str, 0, ( $pos ));

        $arr[] = $pos;
    }


    return $arr;
}

/**
 * Test
 *
 */
$str1 = "Loremsdn ?? kksadh? jasd?";
$res1 = getPositions( $str1, "?" );
var_dump( $res1 ); echo "<hr>";

$str2 = "Loremsdn eops selions sshr";
$res2 = getPositions( $str2, "s" );
var_dump( $res2 ); echo "<hr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser una opción usar [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php) donde los parámetros son :

1. El patrón de búsqueda *(Cadena)* , por ejemplo `"/mundo/"`  buscará la palabra mundo en la cadena
2. La cadena en donde se realizará la búsqueda.
3. Un Arreglo donde se almacenará los valores encontrados
4. Hay tres tipos aquí , pero el que será necesario para este ejercicio será `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` que básicamente es para decir que por cada coincidencia que encuentre , el indice *(inicio)* será agregado al `array` aparte de agregar la cadena que coincidió.*(será la misma)*

**Ejemplo**

```
$cadena = "gran mundo hermoso mundo";
$busqueda = "/mundo/";
preg_match_all($busqueda, $cadena, $indexes, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
print_r($indexes);
```

**Salida**

```
Array ( [0] => 
     Array ( [0] =>
             Array ( [0] => mundo [1] => 5 ) /* Index 5*/
           [1] => 
             Array ( [0] => mundo [1] => 19 ) ) )/* Index 19*/
```

Comment: Parece un poco complicado de implementar y se obtiene un array multi-dimensional... No es lo que estaba buscando.

Comment: Complicado? Más que su función no creo. Pero bueno es la única opción que conozco. Igual puede ayudar a otros usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

Una sola funcion no existe, puedes usar en cambio [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) ejemplo:

```
$str1 = "Loremsdn ?? kksadh? jasd?";

if (strpos($str1, 'Loremsdn') !== false) {
    //Encuentra concurrencia.
    echo 'true';
}
```

podrìas buscar mediante un bucle las concurrencias almacenadas en un array.

Comment: Jorgesys lo que recomienda ya es seguro que lo tiene en su función que planteo. El OP desea encontrar **posiciones** haciendo uso de una sola función,   `strpos`  encuentra la primera **posición**

Comment: Edito respuesta veo que busca un metodo exclusivo para esta operacion.